# Overriding control template with different Windows themes

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a customization over `TextBox`, called `LinkedTextBox` so I have this style defined:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:LinkedTextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:LinkedTextBox">
                <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                         BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush, Converter={StaticResource debugConverter}}" 
                                         Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" >
                    <Grid>
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Margin="3"  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        <Image x:Name="linkButton" Source="../Resources/link-break-icon.png" Width="16" Height="16"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                            Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsLinked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" Property="Background" />
                        <Setter Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" Property="Foreground" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_ContentHost" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_ContentHost" Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="linkButton" Property="Source" Value="../Resources/link-icon.png"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsLinkingEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="linkButton" Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="linkButton" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsLinked" Value="True">
            <!--<Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>-->
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The text box should look like a normal text box, but sometimes it can have a small image, clicking on which I perform some actions and disable/enable the textbox

I am using Windows 7, and this works fine in a standard theme, and the textbox looks exactly like I want. But if I switch to "classic theme" (turning all checkboxes off in Performance Options, under System Properties -> Advanced System Properties from Control Panel), the text box looses it's style completely, and looses it's borders.

The normal text boxes looks ok, and are with the borders. It looks like this:

[image]

On this screenshot there are two text boxes, `LinkedTextBox` is the first and default (original `TextBox`) is the second one.

I assumed that `BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush` should bind `BorderBrush` to the Templates parent `BorderBrush` - which is plain `TextBox`, but for some reason this doesn't work in a classic theme.

I've put debugConverter into the binding and found out that if classic theme is turned on, I receive `00FFFFFF` as solid brush there. If classic theme is turned off, I receive a proper brush with a color and gradient.

I'm not that good in WPF, and styles/templates is not something I use everyday, so I probably have done something silly here. Any advices?

Comment: The built-in WPF controls have separate control templates for each theme. This is a large topic, but if you have a `WPF Unleashed` book, it's describer in Chapter 14.

Comment: @mechanic Thanks for the tip, but unfortunately I don't. And there is no way I can buy one right now. Is there any articles on the web I could read on the topic? Or at least a good google search query, because I have no idea how to search for this, `WPF styles windows theme` yields nothing.

Comment: @mechanic It also sounds weird to me that this is a problem. I do not want to override theme styles. I just want to provide additional button (and some behaviro) to every textBox. I do not specify any specific theme when designing my style. It has `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}"`. So In my mind it should hook up all the styles from the current schema, no matter what current schema is currently on

Comment: You could check the [Control Authoring Overview MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025(v=vs.110).aspx) (the section about themes).

Answer (score 0):

I have a fix so far, but it is quite stupid. Anyway, it works, so unless anybody has a suggestion how to do it properly and relatively simple (I do not want to override manually style for each theme), this might work:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:LinkedTextBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBox x:Name="MyContent" Margin="3" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                 Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                        <Image x:Name="linkButton" Source="../Resources/link-break-icon.png" Width="16" Height="16"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                            Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                    </Grid>
...
```

So to put it simply, I've used the next hack: changed `PART_ContentHost` container with just a normal text box, so it looks always proper in each theme.